# Objective C: How to fit the image inside the imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, aspect-ratio

I am using the UIImagePickerController to select images for my app. But I am facing a issue with the aspect ratio of the selected images.The image is showing larger than its original size and the complete image is not shown.I have tried changing `UIViewContentMode` property to all possible values still no use.Can anyone guide me how to make it work in?

Here is the implementation of UIImagePickerController delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

     self.imageProfile.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
     self.imageProfile.image = image;
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: try to use contentmodescaleaspectfill

Comment: Show us your implementation of `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

Comment: Adjust your image height according your image width and your aspect ratio, check this answer maybe can help you to find out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338392/swift-dynamic-uitableviewcell-size-based-on-image-aspect-ratio/44339968#44339968

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yeah i tried giving the image height and width to the imageview ..even then it is not displaying  full image.

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff ok, i will try to help you, you are using autolayouts?, you can also post the current image aspect and desired?

Comment: yes i am using autolayouts

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff your image don't show all the content in width or height or both, can you please post the current status?, is more likely that your problem is related to constraints

Comment: Yes it dont show all the content in both height and width

Answer (score 0):

Well as you are using autolayouts, first define an outlet with your image height constraint will called `imageHeightConstraint` and then modify your code with this one

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

     float aspectRatio = image.size.height/image.size.width
     self.imageProfile.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
     self.imageProfile.image = image;
     [self.imageHeightConstraint setConstant: self.imageProfile.frame.size.width * aspectRatio];
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

---

### EDITED

this is my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageProfile;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *imageConstraintHeigth;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (IBAction)selectImage:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)editingInfo{

    float aspectRatio = image.size.height/image.size.width;
    self.imageProfile.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.imageProfile.image = image;
    //this if you need adjust heigth according to width
    [self.imageConstraintHeigth setConstant: self.imageProfile.frame.size.width * aspectRatio];

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



@end
```

and this are my constraints [image]

I hope this help, for me works just fine

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff Do you have fixed constraints for width and height?, if don't you must add those because the UIImageView class have intrinsic content size and is growing according the image content

Comment: i have fixed constraints for both width and height

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff I will make my own example, and post my results

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff I will make my own example, and post my results, you need your image showing in a fixed width and height don't you?

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff my answer was edited, i you need further aclarations you must wait y have to leave now, but latter i will check this answer again

Comment: This is what even i have done but i don't know why it is not working for me.Pease post the sample you have done so can check it.

Comment: @ZeenathYousuff check this is my repo https://github.com/rmelian2014/SOImagePickerExampleOBj

Comment: Yeah I checked the sample you have posted and i can see the same result there as well . Actually i am checking in ipad where image shows a very small section of the original image which is enlarged and distorted.