# iOS tableview cell auto imageView height

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

There is only one `UIImageView` in `UITableViewCell`, and the layout is exactly the same as `contentView`. I will show a set of images that look like a long picture.

My current practice is to download all the pictures in order, get the picture width and height, then get the actual height of `UIImageView` according to the screen width, and finally set `heightForRow`. This can work, but it is time consuming.

My question is, must I download the image before I can layout it? Is there a better way?

#### Update：

The ideal effect, without calculating the height, directly adapts to the cell height. Like `label`

Comment: check this maybe can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44338392/swift-dynamic-uitableviewcell-size-based-on-image-aspect-ratio/44339968#44339968

Comment: @ReinierMelian thanks, this is the method I am using now. I am wondering if there is a better way

Comment: @ReinierMelian There is a problem with this method you provide, because `heightForRow` is always executed first, meaning that the height is always inaccurate when it has not started to slide.

Comment: you can use a height by default until the image is loaded, in fact there is in the answer, defaultHeight

Comment: @ReinierMelian You are right, I ignored the refresh `UITableViewCell`

Comment: If that answer helps you please upvote it thanks, let me know if any problem appears

Comment: @ReinierMelian Your method is correct, but it is the same as my previous practice and can work. I am not a problem, but an optimization. I want the effect like the layout `lable`, I don't need to calculate the height, I get the exact height of `cell` automatically. Because you didn't add the answer, I only approve of your comment.

Comment: OK, let me work in an answer for your issue ;)